# Use jQuery or React animations in a reactjs app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, reactjs

I already need to have jQuery included in my app to support necessary jQuery plugins.

Are jQuery animations such as `fadeIn()` fine to use in a reactJs app or do they modify the DOM? Should I be using react animations first unless I absolutely have to use jQuery ones?

I'm a bit confused as to what jQuery functions actually modify the dom.